# How can a serial connection be set up as a network interface if at all?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, interface, serial-port

I have a VM running Ubuntu 14.04 on Windows 7.

My Windows machine is connected to a (CAN bus) data generator which ends in a serial to USB connection. I can forward this connection to the Virtualbox machine.

Essentially, if I do `cat \dev\ttyS0` on my VM, I get to see all the data being broadcast by the generator. But what I really need is a network interface. Is there a way I can forward that data to a network interface called can0?

I've read here: https://developer.ridgerun.com/wiki/index.php/How_to_configure_and_use_CAN_bus

and here:
http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/plain/Documentation/networking/can.txt

that Linux is capable of setting up a CAN network interface, but I am clueless when it comes to how to get that set up.

Comment: If you have some sort of CAN to serial converter, then it is throwing out all of the CAN protocol, isolating a particular data stream from a particular CAN source, and forwarding only that.  There is no going back to real CAN from there.

Comment: @psusi Thanks for the response. I'm still interested in the possibility of forwarding serial data to an interface (even if it's just to prove to my superiors that I need something like a Raspberry PI and a PICAN). Is it technically possible to use a serial connection as an interface?

Comment: No... the only way you can turn a sequence of bytes into an interface for network packets is to encapsulate the packets in a serial frame protocol, otherwise known as ppp, but you seem to be talking about not a device that speaks ppp over a serial line, but totally arbitrary bytes for which there can be no mapping to network packets.